# Laravel ServiceContainer and Facade (beginner)

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

Firs time using the IOC and Facades. I'm trying to make a "teamleader" facade so that I can call

```
Teamleader::getCompaniesByCountry();
```

And I'm getting the error

> Non-static method Notflip\Teamleader\Teamleader::getCompaniesByCountry() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

This is my **ServiceProvider**

```
<?php namespace Notflip\Teamleader;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TeamleaderServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {


    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['teamleader'] = $this->app->bind('teamleader', function($app){
            return new Teamleader();
        });
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And this is my **Facade**

```
<?php namespace Notflip\Teamleader\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Teamleader extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'teamleader'; }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call methods on the facade instead of the actual class. So if your class is `Notflip\Teamleader\Teamleader` and your facade is `Notflip\Teamleader\Facades\Teamleader` then you essentially need to call `Notflip\Teamleader\Facades\Teamleader::getCompaniesByCountry()`.

Obviously you don't want to do that. So you add an alias in your `config/app.php` file. Under the 'Aliases' array you could add:

```
'TeamLeader' => 'Notflip\Teamleader\Facades\Teamleader'
```

Then you can just call `\Teamleader::getCompaniesByCountry()`

In addition, you may need to change you service provider to this:

```
$this->app->bind('teamleader', function($app){
    return new Teamleader();
});
```

Instead of this:

```
$this->app['teamleader'] = $this->app->bind('teamleader', function($app){
    return new Teamleader();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Well written answer and solved!